# Distinct on one column with multiple results

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a problem with my query through visual basic to access database. Lets say I have two tables as bellow.

```
+-------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| ID    | Date1       | Date2       | CustomerID |
+-------+-------------+-------------+------------+
|     1 | 1-1-2013    | 1-1-2012    |          1 |
|     2 | 1-1-2013    | 1-1-2012    |          1 |
|     3 | 1-1-2013    | 1-1-2012    |          2 |
|     4 | 1-1-2013    | 1-1-2012    |          3 |
|     5 | 1-1-2013    | 1-1-2012    |          3 |
+-------+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

and

```
+----------+---------+
| ID       |  Name   |
+----------+---------+
|        1 | John    |
|        2 | Tina    |
|        3 | Patrick |
+----------+---------+
```

I would like to get result with only unique numbers from `Customer - ID` in first table like this one bellow.

```
+----------+----------+-------------+------------+
| ID       |   Date1  |    Date2    | CustomerID |
+----------+----------+-------------+------------+
|        1 | 1-1-2013 | 1-1-2012    |          1 |
|        3 | 1-1-2013 | 1-1-2012    |          2 |
|        4 | 1-1-2013 | 1-1-2012    |          3 |
+----------+----------+-------------+------------+
```

I've tried with this query but with no luck.

```
sqL = " SELECT DISTINCT Order.ID, Order.Date1, Order.Date2, Customer.Name 
FROM Order (Order INNER JOIN Customer ON Order.CustomerID = Customer.ID)"
```

But the code does not give me the result I wanted. Can you please provide me some help with my query.

Comment: I kind of mind the duplicates. Do you really not have a primary key on the table?

Comment: I edited the question so it is more clear. Or not...i know I'm mixing it, but I'm really out of luck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED** This will do it

```
SELECT q.OrderID, o.Date1, o.Date2, o.CustomerID, c.Name AS CustomerName
  FROM 
(
  (SELECT CustomerID, MIN(ID) AS OrderID 
     FROM [Order] 
    GROUP BY CustomerID
  )  AS q INNER JOIN [Order] AS o
  ON q.OrderID = o.ID
) INNER JOIN Customer AS c
ON o.CustomerID = c.ID
```

Output:

```
OrderID | Date1    | Date2    | CustomerID | CustomerName
--------|----------|----------|------------|-------------
1       | 1/1/2013 | 1/1/2012 | 1          | John
3       | 1/1/2013 | 1/1/2013 | 2          | Tina
4       | 1/1/2013 | 1/1/2012 | 3          | Patrick
```

---

**UPDATE:** Based on your comments your real query might look like

```
SELECT q.ID, o.ID_narocila, o.datum_sprejema, o.rok_izdobave, o.status_artikla, o.status_narocila o.ID_stranke, c.naziv
  FROM 
(
  (SELECT ID_stranke, MIN(ID) AS ID
     FROM Narocilo 
    GROUP BY ID_stranke
  )  AS q INNER JOIN Narocilo AS o
  ON q.ID = o.ID
) INNER JOIN Stranke AS c
ON o.ID_stranke = c.ID
```

Comment: I did used this example on my code, but it is returning me mixed rows, but I don't understand why. So I've tried and use sql as shown on picture bellow, but still, same story.  I would like to remove duplicates based on ID_narocila column and select all items that are written in my sql statement. 
[link]http://s16.postimg.org/4x66nscs5/distinct.jpg[/link]

Comment: @user2000139 Can you elaborate what do you mean by *...returning me mixed rows...*? Can you provide sample data on which it produces that effect?

Comment: @user2000139 On the picture that you've posted I don't see remotely the code that I provided in the answer. Where is the subquery?

Comment: I've was editing the comment but you were to fast, sry. I've tried with sql statement as shown below.
`SELECT Narocilo.ID_narocila, MIN(Narocilo.ID_stranke) AS MindOfID_stranke, MIN(Stranke.naziv) AS AsMinOfNaziv, MIN(Narocilo.datum_sprejema) AS MinOfdatum_sprejema, 
MIN(Narocilo.rok_izdobave)  AS MinOfrok_izdobave, MIN(Narocilo.status_artikla) AS MinOfStatusA, MIN(Narocilo.status_narocila) AS MinOfStatusN 
FROM (Narocilo INNER JOIN  Stranke ON Narocilo.ID_stranke = Stranke.ID) 
GROUP BY Narocilo.ID_narocila`

Comment: @user2000139 Again it's not the code that I provided. You missing the critical part innermost subquery that select **ONLY** `MIN(date)` per Customer and then JOINs back to the same table to grab actual values from other columns. On the contrary what you do is you select min values for every column in a group which gives you mixed results.

Comment: @user2000139 See updated answer. I'm not completely sure that I correctly deduced all the column names but your query should look very similar to that. Let me know how did it go.

Comment: Peter thank you for your effort. I'm still having trouble.
I've translated table columns
`**ITEM**
ID,
order_ID,
customerID,
date_order,
date_delivery,
item_status,
order_status,
**CUSTOMER**
ID,
name
`

I wanna to get different items from cell order_ID. It's a must that I need also ID on ITEM in this query? Don't know if u understand me what I want.

Comment: Peter thanks once more, i figured it out now. Your code above works as expected.

Comment: @user2000139 Great. I'm glad it worked out for you. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

From the desired result set you have shown, the following query will work:

```
SELECT Min(T2.ID) AS MinOfID, Min(T1.Date1) AS MinOfDate1, Min(T1.Date2) AS MinOfDate2, T1.CustomerID
FROM T2 INNER JOIN T1 ON T2.ID = T1.CustomerID    
GROUP BY T1.CustomerID;
```